# (NEAR protocol) How to get the Validator Node up

Tags: nearprotocol-validator, near

I am trying to run a validator node using the https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/node/validator/deploy-on-mainnet instruction. I have successfully deployed mainnet Staking Pool with the following command (2nd step of the instruction):

```sh
near call poolv1.near create_staking_pool '{"staking_pool_id":"<name_of_pool>", "owner_id":"<wallet_name>.near", "stake_public_key":"ed25519:3QohztWwCktk3j3MBiCuGaB6vXxeqjUasLan6ChSnduh", "reward_fee_fraction": {"numerator": 3, "denominator": 100}}' --account_id <wallet_name>.near --amount 30 --gas 300000000000000
```

The transaction
https://explorer.mainnet.near.org/transactions/93xQC8UozL6toVddkPk14qiExdRZMt3gJqCfHz9BBNpV

But after starting NEAR node, the database synchronization does not start (3nd step of the instruction).

```sh
target/release/neard run
```

[image: near node]

The operating system listens on ports 3030 and 24567. Both ports are open in the Firewall.

Comment: If you post console screenshots always provide the console contents as text (e.g. so other can find it when searching).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `boot_nodes` to `config.json`.

```sh
rm ~/.near/config.json
wget -O ~/.near/config.json https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/build.nearprotocol.com/nearcore-deploy/mainnet/config.json
```

After that, the node started

```sh
Nov 01 12:08:09.253  INFO stats: #51601485 EgEtVtQuGmvAkpRdjMb6rRwc7qjh2wYEKtmoWuqTDxf5 -/60 33/27/40 peers ⬇ 314.7kiB/s ⬆ 252.9kiB/s 0.80 bps 100.56 Tgas/s CPU: 26%, Mem: 6.0 GiB 
Nov 01 12:08:19.256  INFO stats: #51601494 73BhJpUURFQU36Npgi5VajgJxPNdfuF3TJKFHneeA3Pd -/60 33/27/40 peers ⬇ 318.9kiB/s ⬆ 253.2kiB/s 0.90 bps 109.87 Tgas/s CPU: 24%, Mem: 6.0 GiB 
Nov 01 12:08:29.299  INFO stats: #51601503 4o7iuNUaypY6KQphhrEYoGU5ZRECyPwyM7Vge8AVnsYq -/60 33/27/40 peers ⬇ 313.7kiB/s ⬆ 247.1kiB/s 0.90 bps 116.37 Tgas/s CPU: 28%, Mem: 6.0 GiB 
Nov 01 12:08:39.303  INFO stats: #51601511 GxQePJAQBrirSNwt7uraNeWqXGFZG1YkpKLJfX4Wd9Pb -/60 33/27/40 peers ⬇ 313.6kiB/s ⬆ 247.9kiB/s 0.80 bps 78.89 Tgas/s CPU: 22%, Mem: 6.0 GiB 
Nov 01 12:08:49.306  INFO stats: #51601520 9HzEv22KpcGmip83s9T3FqmKB9qbH6Mu1Cdh8cULf9BN -/60 33/27/40 peers ⬇ 319.0kiB/s ⬆ 250.8kiB/s 0.90 bps 98.36 Tgas/s CPU: 25%, Mem: 6.0 GiB 
Nov 01 12:08:59.309  INFO stats: #51601529 7NaEtQW8qp1jtZ3CbzRFcjzjjFx4DLtT9bUCc1CVRCB8 -/60 33/27/40 peers ⬇ 318.7kiB/s ⬆ 250.9kiB/s 0.90 bps 115.87 Tgas/s CPU: 24%, Mem: 6.0 GiB
```